# Python "import django" not finding module; what's it looking for?

Tags: python, windows, django, google-app-engine, path

Very basic, newbie question on setting up Django for Google App Engine in a Windows 7 development environment.

I have a **Django** folder under the **google_appengine** folder, with all the Django distribution folders (as described in [an All Buttons Pressed djangoappengine doc](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine)) under the **Django** folder.

Using the App Engine Launcher and specifying the path to the django-testapp folder, I was able to successfully run the **ctst** script and get the "It works!" message.

So here's the problem: Exactly how do I figure out what path to add to the Windows PATH env variable so that this doesn't happen when I try to run the Python 2.7 interpreter to confirm that Python (outside the App Engine Launcher) can see Django?

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

What file is the Python interpreter looking for?  Beyond that, is there a recommended directory setup for Django, the App Engine SDK, and Python itself that will simplify life?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the SDK (the google_appengine directory); stuff you put there won't be automatically picked up by the dev_appserver, and certainly won't be uploaded with your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Python looks for its modules via the `PATH` environment variable.  You can add the relevant directory to `PYTHON_PATH` though and it should pick that up.

Another (probably better) solution would be to move the appropriate directory into your Python `site-packages` directory and making sure it is appropriately named.

Comment: After asking my question, more blog searching told me that the **django** folder from **django-nonrel** needs to be moved into _/Lib/site-packages/_ in the Python27 folder.  Then the interpreter could execute the "import django" command.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, the `site-packages` directory is searched for these modules, so that's another (probably better) way to do it, certainly.  I'll add that information to the answer.